# pass requests between public and private subnets AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, nat, amazon-vpc

I have 2 Nginx servers behind a load balancer. These servers are in a public subnet. I have a MongoDB instance and that is in a private subnet. Both are in the same VPC. My question can I route the traffic from my load balancer to the MongoDB and receive a response from my MongoDB without having a NAT gateway or bastion server. I know a NAT gateway or a bastion server is needed to ssh into my instance but that is not my purpose. I just want to receive responses from my MongoDB in the private subnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All resources in the same VPC can communicate with each other, regardless of subnet.

Simply make sure that the **Security Group** on each resource permits the inbound connection.

For example, you should have:

- A security group for the load balancer (`LG-SG`) that permits incoming traffic from the Internet
- A security group for the Nginx servers (`NGINX-SG`) that permits incoming traffic from `LG-SG`
- A security group for the MongDB server (`MONGO-SG`) that permits incoming traffic from `NGINX-SG` or `LG-SG` (depending where incoming traffic is coming from)

By default, security groups are configured to **permit all Outbound traffic**, and security groups are stateful. This means that responses to requests will automatically be able to return to the sender. There is no need to specifically permit return-path access.